# export dataframe to json with two filters

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a data frame df that i want to export to json output. I also need to filter on two columns, say column a and column b. By default, i need to export the entire data frame but i also want to pass values to column a and column b as optional variables to export certain data only. For example, when col a = "yes" and col b = "red", export it. i tried this : df.to_json but I want to know how to filter as well. 
How can i achieve that? I am new to pandas and python, please provide more detailed explanation. Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: It would be helpful if you had a basic dataframe to create a reproducible result.

Comment: What if col a is not "yes" or col b is not "red"?

Comment: col a could be yes or no, col b could be 'red', 'black' , 'green', 'blue' and etc. to put it in a sql way: it is similar to select * from table and select * from table where col a = ''yes' and col b = ' red'. However, the where condition is optional. by default it should export all but when i specify the condition it needs to export only certain data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `&` (`and`), but is necessary also check if need all values. Solution is add another conditions and chaining with `|` (`or`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col a':['yes','no','yes', 'yes'],
                   'col b':['red','green','orange','red']})
print (df)
  col a   col b
0   yes     red
1    no   green
2   yes  orange
3   yes     red

def filtering(a='ALL',b='ALL'):

    m1 = df['col a'] == a
    m2 = df['col b'] == b
    m3 = a == 'ALL'
    m4 = b == 'ALL'
    return df[(m1|m3) & (m2|m4)].to_json() 

print (filtering())
{"col a":{"0":"yes","1":"no","2":"yes","3":"yes"},
"col b":{"0":"red","1":"green","2":"orange","3":"red"}}

print (filtering('yes','red'))
{"col a":{"0":"yes","3":"yes"},"col b":{"0":"red","3":"red"}}
```

EDIT:

For filtering by lists of values is solution similar, only conditions are changed - need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and `in` (change `ALL` to some universal value never in data):

```
def filtering(a=['ALL'],b=['ALL']):

    m1 = df['col a'].isin(a)
    m2 = df['col b'].isin(b)
    m3 = 'ALL' in a
    m4 = 'ALL' in b
    return df[(m1|m3) & (m2|m4)].to_json() 
print (filtering())
{"col a":{"0":"yes","1":"no","2":"yes","3":"yes"},
"col b":{"0":"red","1":"green","2":"orange","3":"red"}}

print (filtering(['yes'],['red', 'orange']))
{"col a":{"0":"yes","2":"yes","3":"yes"},
"col b":{"0":"red","2":"orange","3":"red"}}
```

Comment: this helps but how to make these two conditions optional?

Comment: What does it mean? Can you explain more? or need some character instead `red` for export all rows, similar for `yes` ?

Comment: i need a function to export the data frame to json with all the data as default and optional filtering on col a and col b. suppose i have this function df2json(df, a, b). a(yes) and b (red) would be the optional variables to pass to that function.

Comment: is there any better way to do this? i dont think writing out the values of col b is a good option. what if col b contains 100 of different values? I want to vote your answer but it doesn't meet my expectation yet. sorry and thank you so much!